# Download all files from a folder on Server in Android

Tags: android, android-download-manager

Currently i am downloading individual files inside folder on server. But i want to download all the files inside the folder (on server). How can i do that?

I got this answer after research `"I would suggest you to have a script at server's end, which first gives you list of all the files inside a folder, and then your application downloads each file one by one."` but i don't have knowledge about script at server end. So how is it possible through Android Code?

**Individual File Download Code**

```
public void myDownload(String myURL) {

    DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(myURL));
    request.setTitle("File Download");
    request.setDescription("Downloading....");

    //request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI);
    request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
    request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
    //request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_HIDDEN);
    String nameOfFile = URLUtil.guessFileName(myURL, null, MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(myURL));

    //request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/KiiTTimeTableData/" + year + "/" + branch + "/" + section + "/", nameOfFile);
    //request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir("/MyDataFinal/", nameOfFile);
    request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, nameOfFile);

    DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
    manager.enqueue(request);
}
```

Comment: Possible through android code? Just ask for the list as you now do for that url. If the list is downloaded parse all urls out of it. Then use all urls as usual. So the point is that you dont need special Android code but a server script that lists all files in a folder. If it is a webserver put directory listing on for that folder and use jsoup to parse the resulting html file.